# What is the best statistical test to use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I would like to compare two lots of data sets that have come from two locations.
I am trying to test the null hypothesis that there is no difference between site A and Site B, with respect to multiple field measures.

Each location has multiple data sets.
The data set looks like this

Site A has data variables Total Species count A, Total Species count B, Total Species count C, total Species count D, & total Species count E.

Site B has the same (e.g data variables Species A, Species B, Species C, Species D, & Species E)

Which stat is best to test this hypothesis?
thank you.
B

Comment: For count data it would seem logical to describe the data through some count distribution (e.g. negative binomial or Poisson) and to have some regression model to take into account any known explanatory factors (e.g. duration of observation as an offset, vegetation, cover, food sources etc.). Are you interested in whether the count for species A is different between locations, separately whether the Count for species B is different etc. or whether all species differ between locations in the same/similar manner? Should counts for different species be related (e.g. do they need similar things?)?

Comment: Sites A and B are from the same pond but it has been separated by a road. We are trying to see if there is a difference in the food availability for birds between the 2 sites. We are looking at various factors which could further explain the differences (e.g pH, EC, Cl) The two sites have three rep's and we are looking at the Benthic Infauna differences, in the water column and on the bottom of pond surface. So yes we are looking for differences in the total species A vs species B etc and trying to see if this can explain why birds prefer one pond over the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a contingency table and analyse effects using log-linear modelling or a chi-square test. The choice depends on what kind of effect you are looking for: main effects or an interaction effect. This presentation gives a nice and compact overview of the subject matter: http://www.uni-tuebingen.de/fileadmin/Uni_Tuebingen/SFB/SFB_833/A_Bereich/A1/Christoph_Scheepers_-_Statistikworkshop.pdf